# google map language only english

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

In google maps, I want only english language without other languages. Now, if I'm looking, for example, at city in Russia, I will see Moscow wrote in English and on the bottom the russian name.

[english map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue1Sf.png)

when the code is:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&language=en&region=FR&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I want the map to display names only in english.

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: please look at this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapTypeStyle

Comment: I already search there but I didn't found nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cant do that - you can only hide all labels using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference)